# How to return custom json response with Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Actually i return json from some media files depends on url `<str:scene>` varialbe is set. I just want to use rest framework interface and auth token so i think that could be easier way to present my data.
Here what i do:

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import views
from django.http import JsonResponse

class Manager(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, scene):
        return JsonResponse({'get': scene})

    def post(self, request, scene):
        return JsonResponse({'post': scene})
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', views.Manager)

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:scene>', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This code requires me to use `basename` argument in `path` but since i don't use models i haven't anything to pass in it.

So what is the way to return my custom json data using rest framework interface?

Comment: This post has 500+ views 3 answers with one accepted and **0** votes. Everything is clean in it it's not a duplicate it implements the official recommendations and I believe it helped at least to 10% of it's viewers and it has **0** votes.. and now I have the posting ban because **"asking questions is privilege not a right"**. But I always have like -2 -3 votes with 20-30 viewers if I did some mistake or I was not 100% origin. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add the [**`APIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views) to the routers as the [routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) are meant for [**`ViewSet`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) classes. Also, in DRF, it is good to use the [**`Response`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response) class instead of `JsonResponse`

```
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response


class Manager(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, scene):
        return Response({'get': scene})

    def post(self, request, scene):
        return Response({'post': scene})
```

Now, change the URL patterns as,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:scene>', Manager.as_view(), name='manager-view'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already giving out json data

Comment: No, actually it gives me `AssertionError` cause i don't specify `basename` in `path`

Comment: Your base url should be something like this from django.contrib import admin from django.urls import path, include urlpatterns = [ path('admin/', admin.site.urls), path("api/", include("your_app_name.urls")) ] 
In your app url do this..
app_name = "your app name"

urlpatterns = [
    # path("pathname/<str:scene>", view_class_name.as_viee, name="view-name")
]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where this JsonResponse comes from (if it's a dependency) but the DRF has the `Response` that will return the json it needs.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class Manager(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request, scene):
        return Response({'get': scene})

    def post(self, request, scene):
        return Response({'post': scene})
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work since i don't specify `basename` in `path`